# git cant see changes in repository (bare repository?)- ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu

Apologies in advance as I am still getting to grips with git.

Using ubuntu,

Firstly on Server A:

- I created a repository
- I created another folder (folderB) on that server and used `git clone` to be able to commit to that repository

This worked fine and was committing with no issues

Secondly on Server B:

- I created a folder and used `git clone` to get the remote repo (Server A)
- I successfully used `git pull`. When I went to `git push`, it wouldnt work, I received several errors along the lines of

  `remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master`

  `remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
  remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
  remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
  remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.`
- So I then ran `git config --bool core.bare true` , admittedly, I dont know what this command did (just learning here), someone had it as a solution on stackoverflow.
- Afterwards my `git push` worked perfectly. However I dont see the file changes.

It is succesfully going to the remote repository, the reason I know this is because when I ran `git pull` on folderB (see above) it pulled all the changes from Server B.

My problem is I dont see those file changes on the original repository.

My intention is to be able to deploy code in an instance, i.e. make the live server the repository.

Comment: Not seeing the file changes is exactly what you would expect with a bare repository

Comment: Ok thanks, its occured to me that ive been doing it the wrong way around, i should just pull onto the live server, instead of pushing onto it